# Discatenate in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, visual-studio-macros

I have a list of IP addresses, lets say as follow:

```
192.168.1.1
192.1688.2.1
192.168.3.1
```

Now I would like to write a macro in excel where when I enter an IP address in a column, for instance 192.168.3.48, it should search the first three segment (192.168.3) from the list and add a string into another cell.

For instance if the first three segment of the ip address would be 192.168.3 then it should add APP else something else.

I could have achieved this very easily in Java or any other programming language but its sought of tricky when it comes to excel.

Normal logic would be to Discatenate the first three segment from the input IP address and then search this new string from the list. If it was found then the value is true (Or in this case APP). I am really confused on how to achieve this in excel.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you are working in VBA, the "dis-concatenate" function is called `Split`.  It will give an array of pieces where you can take the first 3 and combine back together (using `Join`).  If in normal Excel (formulas only), the relevant function is probably `FIND` where you search for a period and then `LEFT` `RIGHT` or `MID` to extract pieces.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straight forward.

Use `LEFT` to get the first three characters out of the cell in question. Example:

```
=LEFT(A1,3)
```

Then use `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the cross referenced string:

```
=INDEX(MY_LOOKUP_TABLE_2ND_COLUMN,MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),MY_LOOKUP_TABLE_1ST_COLUMN,0))
```

If you are entering your IP address in column A, you would put the above formula in column B. If there is nothing entered in column A, this formula will produce an error. You can suppress that error this way:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MY_LOOKUP_TABLE_2ND_COLUMN,MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),MY_LOOKUP_TABLE_1ST_COLUMN,0)),"")
```

Create your lookup table elsewhere in your workbook (like on another sheet). It would just look like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2
192         APP
```

EDIT: Upon rereading your question, I think I may have misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a reply. But this is not what I was expecting for. Anyway I will add my answer in a while. I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the list of IP addresses is in the column A in cells A2, A3, A4 and so on.

You can search for the position of the 3rd decimal point in cell A2 by the following formula:

```
=SEARCH(".",A2,SEARCH(".",A2,SEARCH(".",A2,1)+1)+1)
```

and 3rd decimal point in cell A3 by the following:

```
=SEARCH(".",A3,SEARCH(".",A3,SEARCH(".",A3,1)+1)+1)
```

If these positions are stored in B2, B3, B4 and so on... you can separate the required text by using the Left formula:

```
=LEFT(A2,B2-1)
=LEFT(A3,B3-1)
```

After this, you may use vlookup and check whether the input string matches these or not.